# Customize the table view using initWithStyle in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2

This is the existing source code in Objective-C.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"mdm.agent.common.desktopCentral", nil);
    }
    return self;
}
```

How do I customise the tableview like this using `init()` and how to retrn back the cell after initialization when I convert this to swift 2.0? Thank you in advance.